# Socket creation

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

In my client-server application, I am creating a Socket with ipaddress and port number.

Initially when we run client application, socket with server is established. But after multiple closing and starting of the client application, it is throwing exception and socket is not getting created(even though a system with the specified ipaddress exists).

I am unable to trace the mistake. Can you suggest me,where i am going wrong?

Comment: What exception is thrown? Can you paste the full stack trace?

Comment: It's not much to go on. If you restrat the client does it work? If so it is likely you are not closing your client's sockets correctly and you are running out of resources (possibly on the client or the server)

Comment: But if i restart client app after some time say 3 or 4 minutes,problem is getting resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bind to a specific port in the client. Just let the implementation select what port to bind to.

Comment: But my requirement is that my Client sholud connect to server with specific port number(say 10000).

Comment: What does that have to do with what port you *bind* to? Of course you must *connect* to the server's well known port number.

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on OS but when your app begins refusing to establish a new connection run `netstat.exe` (Windows) and you will see a lot of TCP connections in `TIME_WAIT` state. TCP connections get into this state after they are closed and stay in it for some time. That means OS can run out of free connections when you open / close them quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Socket.setSoLinger(false, 0) so the socket will be closed immediately.